# App.config file not being recognized in by PayPal.Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal

I want to eventually set up Paypal payment. Step one though is to have a play. And I have failed on the quick start!

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/wiki/Quick-Start shows a code example. It explains that first, I need to download the `PayPal .NET SDK` package via NuGet. This is great, I'm on .NET Framework (not core). I install it.

Phase 2 gives an entire example. I add some PayPal config settings to the app.config file. Done

Phase 3 is where it is going wrong. I'm referencing PayPal.API in my C# class.

The relevant part of my code is

```
using PayPal.Api;
using System.Collections.Generic;   

namespace TestProj.Payment
{
    public class PaypalGateway
    {
        public void Sandbox()
        {
            var config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();// this is the fault
            var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();
```

`config` always has 0 instances

My Project has an App.config file with the correct values

```
 <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="paypal" type="PayPal.SDKConfigHandler, PayPal" />
  </configSections>
  <paypal>
    <settings>
      <add name="mode" value="sandbox" />
      <add name="clientId" value="***" />
      <add name="clientSecret" value="***" />
    </settings>
  </paypal>
```

If I rename my `App.config` file to `blah.nonsense` then the same issue occurs. It's as if the API is looking for a file else where or that it isn't configured correctly.

Comment: Have you added the app.config to the same process that you start the system with?  Or is the `PaypalGateway` called from another hosting process?

Comment: That should be the problem then, add the config to the hosting process's app.config, should sort it out

Comment: Sorry, I had done.(I removed my comment saying no I didn't). Both my ManualTest proj and the project with this code contain the same config details (as I do with EF connection strings) @3dd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is tagged with [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc), so the assumption is that this is for a web project

The quick start clearly states

> Add the following to your **web.config** or **app.config**

`web.config` should where you place the configuration details if this is in fact a web project.

Even if the referenced code is for another class library in the project, which can use `app.config` file, all the settings will eventually have to be in the root `web.config` file of the web project as that is the process that will be running.

Comment: This is the answer, but I'm now confused. It is a web project. There is the MVC.NET project, a Payment Project (class library) and a Test project. I'm executing directly from my test project to the Payment Project. As such, I'm never touching the MVC.NET project, but as you point out, it is needed. I'm totally surprised by this

Comment: is the test project running a unit test or calling the web project in an integration test? Makes a big difference. If running unit test then the unit- test's app.config is to be used as that is what will be running. if calling the web project via direct http calls then the web.config is needed for the web server.

Comment: No, the test unit is not calling it at all. As far as I can see, it's totally independent from the MVC project. However, I guess there are http calls because it's Paypal and it's authenticating. Thankyou…

Answer (score 0):

the same problem was with me, the keyword PayPal must be in small caps like paypal.

```
<configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="paypal" type="PayPal.SDKConfigHandler, **PayPal**" />
  </configSections>
  <paypal>
    <settings>
      <add name="mode" value="sandbox" />
      <add name="clientId" value="***" />
      <add name="clientSecret" value="***" />
    </settings>
  </paypal>

should be

<configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="paypal" type="PayPal.SDKConfigHandler, **paypal**" />
  </configSections>
  <paypal>
    <settings>
      <add name="mode" value="sandbox" />
      <add name="clientId" value="***" />
      <add name="clientSecret" value="***" />
    </settings>
  </paypal>
```