# c# net(vs code) paypal 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, .net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to use paypal in my net core project using vs code, however i got error

```
Shop.Api.Controllers.OrderController: Error: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'PayPal.Api.ConfigManager' threw an exception.
 ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'PayPal.Log.LogConfiguration' threw an exception.
 ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
   at PayPal.Log.LogConfiguration.GetConfiguration(String name)
   at PayPal.Log.LogConfiguration.GetConfigurationLoggerList()
   at PayPal.Log.LogConfiguration..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at PayPal.Log.Logger..ctor(Type givenType)
   at PayPal.Log.Logger.GetLogger(Type givenType)
   at PayPal.Api.ConfigManager..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at PayPal.Api.ConfigManager.GetConfigWithDefaults(Dictionary`2 config)
   at PayPal.Api.OAuthTokenCredential..ctor(String clientId, String clientSecret, Dictionary`2 config)
   at Shop.Api.Controllers.OrderController.CreateOrderAsync(CreateOrderDto createOrder) in C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Shop\ShopBackend\Shop.Api\Controllers\OrderController.cs:line 172
```

```
  Dictionary<string, string> config = new Dictionary<string, string>();

  var clientId = this.configuration.GetSection("Paypal:__CLIENT_ID__").Value;
  var clientSecret = this.configuration.GetSection("Paypal:__CLIENT_SECRET__").Value;
  var mode = this.configuration.GetSection("Paypal:mode").Value;
            
  config.Add("clientId", clientId);
  config.Add("clientSecret", clientSecret);
  config.Add("mode", mode);

  var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(clientId, clientSecret, config).GetAccessToken();

  var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken){
      Config = config
  };       

  var payment = new Payment()
  {
       intent = "sale",
       payer = payer,
       transactions = transactionList,
       redirect_urls = redirUrls
  };
```

Error happens on accessToken line, but it happens later(payment, apiContext) if i delete that line.

appsettings.json(also variables like clientId are loaded corerctly)

```
 "Paypal": {
    "mode": "sandbox",
    "__CLIENT_ID__": "clilentId",
    "__CLIENT_SECRET__": "clilentSecret"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [PayPal SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/wiki/Configuration) is looking for a web.config or app.config file:

> In order to use the PayPal .NET SDK with your application, you will
> need to first configure your application. By default, the SDK will
> attempt to look for PayPal-specific settings in your application's
> web.config or app.config file.

You should add these required configuration specifications to your web.config or app.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="paypal" type="PayPal.SDKConfigHandler, PayPal" />
  </configSections>

  <!-- PayPal SDK settings -->
  <paypal>
    <settings>
      <add name="mode" value="sandbox" />
      <add name="clientId" value="__CLIENT_ID__" />
      <add name="clientSecret" value="__CLIENT_SECRET__" />
    </settings>
  </paypal>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If you're still stuck, check out this very similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54158562/app-config-file-not-being-recognized-in-by-paypal-api

Comment: app.config and web.config are only for visual studio, i am using visual studio code, where appsettings.json is replacment for that files.

Comment: @algorithms u should create manualy your own app.config or web.config